# How to group by data in postgresql by timestamp and distinct values?

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime

This is my current table format :

```
userName userId recordedAt
Deepesh    1    2021-03-29 07:20:36
Sushant    2    2021-03-29 07:27:55
Ankita     3    2021-03-29 07:30:40
Aman       4    2021-03-29 07:39:15
Ankita     3    2021-03-29 07:51:29
Suman      5    2021-03-29 07:55:19
Ankita     3    2021-03-29 08:36:55
```

I want to query data in such a way that it should count the distinct userId and then group it by hour. Expected result -

```
time   userLogged
07:00      5
08:00      1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY date_trunc()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
SELECT recordedAt, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS userLogged FROM table_name GROUP BY recordedAt;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to group by minute, hour, day, week, etc., it's tempting to just group by your timestamp column, however, then you'll get one group per second, which is likely not what you want. Instead, you need to "`truncate`" your timestamp to the granularity you want, like minute, hour, day, week, etc. The PostgreSQL function you need here is `date_trunc`.

```
select
  date_trunc('minute', created_at), -- or hour, day, week, month, year
  count(1)
from users
group by 1
```

Comment: This is counting same user id twice, i want distinct value